# Android CameraX multiple Analyzers

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

Is it possible to add multiple `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` instances (use cases) at the same time using CameraX API?

For instance:

You need to run an *Object Detector* and *Barcode Detector* **simultaneously**.

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Only one analyzer could be registered at any time](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#setAnalyzer(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis.Analyzer)). You might have to chain your analyzers in your app with its own image copies, probably in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

**Setting an analyzer function replaces any previous analyzer. Only one analyzer can be set at any time.**

Setting an analyzer will signal to the camera that it should begin sending data. The stream of data can be stopped by calling clearAnalyzer()